# How to generate a grid(Table) with a foreach

Tags: foreach, html-table, cakephp-2.0

My problem is simple, but I'm beginning with cakephp. I'll explain my problem:

I have 2 tables:

```
Table: Expenditures
Columns:
sub_category_id 
account_id  
date    
ammount     
created     
modified    
description

Table: BudgetRecords
Columns:
budget_id   
ammount     
sub_category_id 
created     
modified
```

I have a 'home-work' to do, and my teacher wants me to do a report. This report will generate a table, and will show an balance (Expenditures.ammount - BudgetRecords.ammount), and each month (BudgetRecords.created, or Expenditures.date, whatever).

Here's my question: I'm trying to do a foreach, passing for each year (if exists), if a year exists, then execute a query for each month. But, how I do that with CakePHP? I've tried to do this only inside the Controller, and it runs fine. But returns me only the last month of the last year. Then, I've tried a different approach.

Inside the View, execute the query and search if exists the year. If exists, then search for this month. Then gives me back the result.

That's what I did:

Inside the View:

```
<table align="center" border="2" rules="All">
    <tr>
        <td>Valor:</td>
        <td>Data:</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
        if (strlen($month) == 1)
            $month = '0' . $month;

        foreach ($Expenditure->SaldoMes($month) as $result) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> R$:" . $result[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td> " . $result[1] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Inside the Controller:

```
public function SaldoMes($month = null) {
    $month = 0;
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
        if (strlen($month) == 1)
            $month = '0' . $month;
        $query = "SELECT (SUM(ex.ammount) - SUM(br.ammount)) as total , br.created as data
                    FROM budget_Records br, expenditure ex 
                    where SUBSTRING(br.created, 6, 2) = '" . $month .
                "' and SUBSTRING(br.created, 6, 2) = SUBSTRING(ex.created, 6, 2)";
        $this->set('Expenditure', $this->Expenditure->query($query));

        foreach ($this->Expenditure->query($query) as $records) {
            $this->set(('Total'), $records[0]['total']);
            $this->set(('Data'), $records['br']['data']);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I've explained my problem well enough for someone to show me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@earlonrails, solved:

```
public function SaldoMes() {
    $result = array();
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
        if (strlen($month) == 1)
            $month = '0' . $month;
        $query = "SELECT (SUM(ex.ammount) - SUM(br.ammount)) as total , br.created as data
                    FROM budget_Records br, expenditure ex 
                    where SUBSTRING(br.created, 6, 2) = '" . $month .
                "' and SUBSTRING(br.created, 6, 2) = SUBSTRING(ex.created, 6, 2)";
        $this->set('Expenditure', $this->Expenditure->query($query));
        foreach ($this->Expenditure->query($query) as $records) {
            $result[$month][0] = $records[0]['total'];
            $result[$month][1] = $records['br']['data'];
        }
    }
    return $this->set('result', $result);
}
```

Using the $result array, now i can get my values.

Thanks for teh help.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

This part is what you are looking for I think. Taken from that website.

```
<?php
# /app/Controller/RecipesController.php

class RecipesController extends AppController {
    public function view($id) {
        //action logic goes here..
    }

    public function share($customer_id, $recipe_id) {
        //action logic goes here..
    }

    public function search($query) {
        //action logic goes here..
    }
}
```

"The view files for these actions would be app/View/Recipes/view.ctp, app/View/Recipes/share.ctp, and app/View/Recipes/search.ctp. The conventional view file name is the lower cased and underscored version of the action name."

So if you wanna just use another method like SaldoMes() then just call it in the view method.

Comment: i've already said that on my problem's description. I know a bit how to use Model, Controller and View, but i don't know how to call a method inside the Controller, to search for a year, a month and build the table.

Comment: I need to call this method in a foreach, and inside that method, will receive a value in his assignature and execute a query by month/year.

Comment: ok then maybe you are looking for more like this. http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/434/requestAction